# Checking if a number is a multiple of 4

Tags: calculations, etoolbox, conditionals

Using `etoolbox`, `ifthen`, or another form of conditional checking, how can I check if a value is a multiple of 4? E.g. if the number is 4, 8, 12, 16, etc., then it returns "true".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `pgfmath` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\ifismultiple[4]{%
    \pgfmathparse{mod(#1,#2)==0}
    \ifnum \pgfmathresult=1
    #3%
    \else
    #4%
    \fi
}
\ifismultiple{15}{4}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you swap the first two arguments, then you can define a new command `\newcommand\ifismultipleoffour{\ifismultiple{4}}`, etc.

Answer (score 21):

`\ifodd` is enough to do this

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl} 

\newcount\myint

\def\IsFourMultiple#1{% 
\myint#1\relax  
\ifodd\myint 
   false
\else 
  \divide\myint by2\relax
  \ifodd\myint
    false 
  \else 
    true
  \fi
\fi}% 

\begin{document} 

\IsFourMultiple{4}    
\IsFourMultiple{32} 
\IsFourMultiple{15} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that's very clever!

Comment: @Jake But my first idea was to use `pgfmath' like you, because I always have `\usepackage{tikz}` in my preamble. Your solution is more general.

Comment: One drawback (shared by many of the solutions here) is that it is not expandable.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Yes but it is sometimes a desirable and useful feature  but it's not always desirable. Now I would like to know what is the cost in terms of efficiency.

Comment: In many cases, assignments are slower than expandable primitives, which is a reason I avoid them. On the other hand, after some tests, it seems that your approach is the fastest here (I didn't test Aditya's LuaTeX code because my benchmarking code only works in pdfTeX), because it is specifically taylored to the case of 4. In the general case, the `\divide` and the `\numexpr` approaches will take the same time.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: can you explain what you mean by an *expandable* solution and why it's preferable?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: A macro `\macro` (or sequence of macros) is *expandable* if `\edef\foo{\macro}\show\foo` will yield the result. This is, I think, similar to what can appear in a lambda function in Python: no assignment allowed. Expandable solutions are preferable because it is easier to extract the result of those calculations: simply use `\edef`. Also, you can use any expandable command (and only those) within assignments such as `\setlength`, `\addtocounter`, or their plain TeX analogs. Writing the result to a file is also eased.

Answer (score 16):

With eTeX's `\numexpr`, you can do that easily.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doifmultipleof}[2]{%
  \ifnum\numexpr((#2)/(#1))*(#1)-(#2)=0
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \doifmultipleof{4} {6}{true}{false} % => false
  \doifmultipleof{5}{10}{true}{false} % => true
\end{document}
```

Comment: One should note that e-TeX's division rounds, so this method is not suitable to compute the remainder. This doesn't invalidate this solution, of course, as the difference between a multiple of 4 and a non-multiple of 4 can never be 0.

Comment: @egreg. Yes, and the LaTeX3 function `\int_mod:nn` uses some very clever code (by Heiko I believe) to work around that, while avoiding overflow in all cases.

Answer (score 13):

If you can use luatex, then the comparison can be easily done at the lua end. Here is a ConTeXt solution (using named macro arguments):

```
% macros=mkvi

\def\doifmultipleof#{mod}#{num}%
     {\ctxcommand{doifelse(math.mod(#{num}, #{mod}) == 0)}}

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}
  {\doifmultipleof{4}{\recurselevel}{yes}{no}}
\stoptext
```

Comment: +1 because this is the only expandable answer so far (it is expandable, right?). But I have to say, I find the named macro argument syntax quite outlandish. :)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Yes, the code is expandable. As for the named arguments, one can also use `#mod` and `#num`; in fact, those are the recommended alternatives,  but I prefer the `#{...}` variants.

Comment: just curious: with the `#mod` variant, how is the end of the argument name detects? Can you have delimited arguments that way?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\def\IsFourMultiple#1{% 
  \ifdim\dimexpr#1pt/4=\numexpr#1/4pt true\else false\fi}
\begin{document} 

\IsFourMultiple{4}    
\IsFourMultiple{32} 
\IsFourMultiple{15} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\IsFourMultiple{2147483647}`

Comment: _every_ solution has a limit! not really surprising ... ;-)

Comment: Interesting approach. If eTeX is available, you'd better do `\ifdim\dimexpr#1pt/4=\numexpr#1/4pt `: that makes your macro expandable, and probably a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 6):

The [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) can be used to calculate stuff and perform modular arithmetic. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\multoffour}[1]{%
  \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1-(4*trunc(#1/4,0)),0)}% \result contains #1 mod 4
  \ifnumequal{\result}{0}{true}{false}% true = multiple of four; false = not a multiple of four
}
\begin{document}
1 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{1} \par
2 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{2} \par
3 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{3} \par
4 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{4} \par
5 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{5} \par
6 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{6} \par
7 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{7} \par
8 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{8} \par
9 is a multiple of~4: \multoffour{9} \par
\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) was used for numeric comparisons.

---

This works just as well with counters. For example, using

```
\newcounter{mycntr} \setcounter{mycntr}{10}
\multoffour{\themycntr}
```

(provided that `\themycntr` is defined using `\arabic{mycntr}` or not modified).

Comment: Isn't *fp* package (or, for that matter, any package) an overkill for this task? And is this *fp* solution expandable? *fp* solutions are hardly expandable. For non-context and non-lua users, I think Bruno's solution is more than enough, IMHO. And it's superfast. I often get scared by *fp*'s trace log :)

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Sure, there are at least three other answers that produce a package-less solution. Honestly, speed for me is not an issue, since the time difference between `fp`'s output and some other package-less output is most likely less than 0.1 seconds. I rely on code readability, which `fp` provides through its function shorthand/names. If I (or anyone for that matter) is relying on performing *major* calculations within TeX *and* want speed, they are perhaps better off using a different environment altogether. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `expl3` syntax:

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{4}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_compare:nNnTF { \int_mod:nn { \themycounter } {4} } = {0}
      { true }
      { false }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

It checks if your number modulus (basicually remainder after division) 4 is 0.  If the modulus (remainder) is 0, then it is divisible by 4 and executes whatever code is inside `true`. If the modulus is `1`, `2` or `3`, it executes the `false` code. In this case it writes the words `true` or `false` in the PDF output wherever in the document you wrote this.