# CSVTools and Lines Every Fifth line

Tags: tables, longtable, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if a number is a multiple of 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38743/checking-if-a-number-is-a-multiple-of-4)

First, let me apologize for probably a dumb question.  I'm trying to make a table, but I want to use CSVTools because, well mostly because its a lot of data and at a personal level I find intermixing all of this stuff kinda ugly.  What I need to is create a long table where every fifth line has a horizontal line.

I'm looking at examples 7 and 8 from this document:

http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/csvtools/doc/csvtools.pdf

I know the key to this is somehow modifying this line from example 8:

```
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{csvrownumber}}}{%
\\\rowcolor{green}}{\\\rowcolor{blue}}
}
```

But what I need (instead off odd) is a remainder term (ie `if(remainder(csvrownumber/5)==0){ line }).`

Does such a thing exist, is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: `csvtools` is an obsolete package. It has been replaced by `datatool` (by the same author).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an ifthen test for every 5th row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{tst}



\begin{document}

\setcounter{tst}{3}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}

\stepcounter{tst} \thetst: \ifthenelse{\numexpr 5*(\value{tst} / 5) \relax = \value{tst}}{yes}{no}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that uses the `pgf` math functions to provide `\IfMultipleOf` which can be used to test that numbers are multiples of a specified number (defaults to 5):

[image]

### Notes:

- `\IfEq` is from [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% easy way to get pgfmath and \foreach
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\IfMultipleOf}[4][5]{%
    % #1 = optional number to determine multiplicity of (defaults to 5)
    % #2 = number to test
    % #3 = code to execute if multiple of #1
    % #4 = code to execute if not multiple of #1
    %
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\TempRemainder}{mod(#2,#1)}%
    \IfEq{\TempRemainder}{0}{#3}{#4}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}%
\foreach \x in {0,...,10} {%
    \x\ \IfMultipleOf{\x}{is}{is not} a multiple of 5\par
}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}%
\foreach \x in {0,...,10} {%
    \x\ \IfMultipleOf[3]{\x}{is}{is not} a multiple of 3\par
}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER NOTE: this is an answer based on `pgfplotstable` which is *neither* csvtools *nor* `datatool`. I am author of `pgfplotstable`.

Since the question is tagged as "tables longtable tools", I hope that you find the alternative approach using `pgfplotstable` useful:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every nth row={3}{before row=\midrule},
    every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule},
]{
    a b
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
    6 6
    7 7
    8 8
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is an extract of the manual at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf . It uses `booktabs` to generate header/footer lines. Instead of the inline table (i.e. providing table data inside of curly braces), you can also use a file name, i.e.

`\pgfplotstabletypeset[...]{file.csv}`

and you can configure the `col sep` and `row sep` keys if they are not white space/empty line, resp.

In general, the `pgfplotstable` package is a generator for LaTeX `tabular` environments which features 
- number formatting,
- style for columns or rows,
- postprocessing (i.e. computing derived columns out of existing ones),
- highly configurable interface.

In particular, it supports longtable (see the manual examples for the key `begin table`).